# Change the path of images in the Shotwell database

Tags: shotwell

I moved my picture library to a different folder, how can I change the path in the Shotwell database?

Answer (score 4):

Shotwell stores it's data in a SQLite database. You can change the path as follows:

- Close Shotwell;
- Make a backup of `~/.local/share/shotwell/data`;
- Open the database with the command `sqlite3 photo.db` (you may need to install `sqlite3` first with the command `sudo apt install sqlite3`;
- At the prompt (`sqlite>`), type a command like this:

`update PhotoTable set filename =  replace(filename, '/old/path/', '/home/me/new/path/');`

Comment: the `where filename like "/media/media%"` part is not needed.

Comment: If you have raw photos in your library (maybe there are other scenarios this table is used as well) you'll need to make a similar update to `BackingPhotoTable` as well: e.g. `update BackingPhotoTable set filepath = replace(filepath, '/old/path/', '/new/path/');`